# Django filter 'first' lookup for many-to-many relationships

Tags: python, django

Let's say we have a two models like these:

```
Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, related_name='tracks')
```

> How can I filter this relationship to get the first foreign record?

So I've tried something like this, but it didn't work (as expected)

```
artists = Artist.objects.filter(tracks__first__title=<some-title>)
artists = Artist.objects.filter(tracks[0]__title=<some-title>)
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: If you are trying to model a scenario where one Track has multiple artists, I would suggest changes to the model and the relationship.
Using the current technique, you can store the data of multiple Tracks by same Artist.

Comment: not really.. i just want to be able to filter only first record on many_to_many relationship rather then all of them

Comment: Ok. It is simple. 
You want the artist, given a Track title:
Artist.objects.filter(tracks__title=<some_title>)[0]
This will give you the 1st row (ordered by insertion)

Comment: @NagkumarArkalgud I don't want to fetch a first record matching the filter, I want to filter on the first record in the relationship :) So more like `Artist.objects.filter(tracks[0]__title=<some_title>)` which obviously doesn't work but just to illustrate.

Comment: When you say first record in the relationship what does it mean? Is there some ordering defined on Tracks model? How do you decide which track is first? Is it based on the id in the database?

Comment: @AKS it is the first related `Record` to the `Artist` ordered by insertion(id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution not taking performance into consideration.

```
Artist.objects.filter(tracks__in=[a.tracks.first() for a in Artist.objects.all()], tracks__title=<some_title>)
```

No list approach, as requested.

```
Artist.objects.filter(tracks__in=Track.objects.all().distinct('artist').order_by('artist', 'id'), tracks__title=<some_title>)
```

The order_by 'id' is important to make sure distinct gets the first track based on insertion. The order_by 'artist' is a requirement for sorting distinct queries. Read about it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: thanks for your update, however this is a very inefficient way of doing it, since lists are stored in memory..

Comment: @intelis removed lists. Let me know if it works for you.